# Git clone causing issues with Windows permissions over SSH with django project

Tags: django, git, github, ssh, file-permissions

I've got a Django project which works great. Previously we just cloned down and used password authentication. I changed the remote to `git@bitbucket.org:myteam/our_repo.git`

Recently we started requiring 2FA, so now we can only clone down over SSH.

For this project, I created an access key (read-only, which is all I need for cloning down on a staging server) and I was able to clone down the repo (`git clone git@bitbucket.org:myteam/our_repo.git`) without issue and get it all set up. This *appeared* to have worked.

The other server admin remoted in and tried to run `git pull origin master`, he got a permission issue. His windows user is part of the `Administrators` group - but for some reason that didn't matter. His local user had to be added to the directory with full access before he could run `git pull origin master`

It appears that this permission issue is causing other issues, too. File uploads (from the Django admin) are no longer actually uploading the files into the directory on the server - my guess is that this is related to the permissions issue, too. Nothing was changed to impact this - the project was just cloned down over SSH.

Does cloning something down over SSH change the permissions on the directories or somehow lock it down more? This wasn't an issue before - only since we've switched over to SSH.

Any feedback is helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does cloning something down over SSH change the permissions on the directories or somehow lock it down more?

No, it does not change anything locally.

And 2FA is only impacting HTTPS URL (where your password must be a PAT, Persoanl Access Token)
It has no bearing on SSH URLS.

Check first `ssh -Tv git@github.com` output.

Comment: On [bitbuckets site](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/two-step-verification-777023203.html) they say you can only use SSH with 2FA. HTTPS is not an option when you enable 2FA. This may not be true on other platforms... unsure at this point. I just find it so odd that over https, it was never an issue. Over SSH, big problems with regards to the directories and the permissions on them. Strange.

Comment: @Hanny Yes, that is because 2FA means accessing with HTTPS and a PAT (Personal Access Token), which does not seem to be supported by BitBucket. Hence SSH.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense then, I appreciate your input. Good to know it shouldn't have any affect on the permissions of the folders, either. That must be something on Windows end then - just never had these issues over https on deployment. I'm probably misattributing them to git when there is something else going on. Thanks again!